# Como puedo recuperar datos de Mongodb usando solo electron y el driver de mongodb

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, npm, electron

He intentado poner esta funcion, pero esta lo que hace es solo transformar el doc a string... no se si es la manera correcta...

```
var findPrueba = function (db, callback) {
var cursor = db.collection('prueba').find({});
cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    if (doc != null) {
        var types = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc));
        // var types = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc));
        console.log(types.length);
        for (x = 0; x < types.length; x++) {
            console.log(types[x].usuario);
            console.log(types[x].password);
        }
    } else {
        callback();
    }
});
};
```